# Unable to get JSON rest response into an array through PHP Function

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

So I'm working on expedia's API, and have successfully worked many of the API requests but am unable to get just one to work though I've tried and searched in vain for what could be the problem.

My Function looks like this:

```
global $cid, $apiKey, $sig, $minor_rev;


$url= 'http://api.ean.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/paymentInfo?minorRev='.$minor_rev.'';
$url .= '&cid='.$cid.'';
$url .= '&sig='.$sig.'';
$url .= '&apiKey='.$apiKey.'';
$url .= '&customerUserAgent='.$PaymentTypeData['customerUserAgent'].'';
$url .= '&customerIpAddress='.$PaymentTypeData['customerIpAddress'].'';
$url .= '&customerSessionId='.$PaymentTypeData['customerSessionId'].'';
$url .= '&locale=en_US&_type=json';
$url .= '&amp;currencyCode='.$PaymentTypeData['currencyCode'].'';
$url .= '&hotelId='.$PaymentTypeData['hotelId'].'';
$url .= '&supplierType=E';
$url .= '&rateType=MerchantStandard';



$header[] = "Accept: application/json";
$header[] = "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
$result = json_decode(curl_exec($ch), true);


$HotelPaymentResponse = array();
$HotelPaymentResponse[] = $result['HotelPaymentResponse'];


echo '<pre>';
echo $url;
print_r($result);
echo '<h1>GET HOTEL PAYMENT TYPES</h1>';
print_r($HotelPaymentResponse);
echo '</pre>';

return $HotelPaymentResponse;
```

When I echo the URL and try it in the browser the result is as expected, an array of the payment types in json form.... but for the life of me getting this into the php array for the return eludes me.

Here is a link to the API spec: http://developer.ean.com/docs/payment-types/

And yes I have checked out JSON guides often posted on S.Overflow....

any help would be so very appreciated...

PS:

the API says the repose will look like:

```
{
"HotelPaymentResponse": {
    "@size": "4",
    "@currencyCode": "USD",
    "customerSessionId": "0ABAAAC9-9A32-7914-9E32-D7EC7F906769",
    "PaymentType": [
        {
            "code": "AX",
            "name": "American Express"
        },
        {
            "code": "DS",
            "name": "Discover"
        },
        {
            "code": "CA",
            "name": "Master Card"
        },
        {
            "code": "VI",
            "name": "Visa"
        }
    ]
}
}
```

BUT my Array is returning:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
)
```

SOLVED:

Thanks to working through the comments below and researching the error thrown, 505 - I googled and found someone say they had an error because of a stray space in the url. My error was because my Customer user agent was populating from php's user HTTP agent... Removed that and manually entered and now I can curl the response.

Comment: Does it throws an error?

Comment: No error being thrown, but the array is printing Array
(
    [0] => 
)

Comment: run a var_dump() on the $result and see what it shows. If it's NULL, then your array will be empty, and there's an issue in your API call

Comment: Yeah it is NULL, but what I don't understand is that when I visit the echoed URL it shows up fine in the browser - any ideas?

Comment: This specific bit: `echo $url;
print_r($result);` What does that show?

Comment: echo $url; echoes the $url and when I copy paste to the browser address bar, it works fine - print_r($result) is showing me Array ( [0] => )

Comment: I'm getting a response back, and it's due to being unauthenticated. So you should at least be getting something back. Here's an image to show my response. All I did was remove "true" from json_decode() [Response - Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/m8TUxLt.png)

Comment: I know I should be, I get the full response no errors when copy pasting the echo url in the browser

Comment: If you're on Linux, run `curl -i <URL>` with the api keys. Also, add these two to your cURL call: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);` and see if you get the headers. They should help with working on the response, assuming the API is giving you one.

Comment: Echoes: HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version not supported
Server: EAN
Content-Length: 0
Date: Fri, 08 Apr 2016 17:24:04 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Comment: That seems to be the issue there. I'm not familiar with their API or how they handle their API end-points. I'd investigate their docs a bit further.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `true` as the second argument to `json_decode`, JSON objects are decoded to PHP associative arrays, not objects. So `$result->HotelPaymentResponse` should be `$result['HotelPaymentResponse']`.

Or don't use the second argument to `json_decode()`.

Comment: Thanks, I did try that but still throwing Array ( [0] => )

Comment: What does the response from the API look like before you call `json_decode()`?

Comment: I'm not sure hot to check that?

Comment: `$response = curl_exec($ch); var_dump($response); $result = json_decode($response, true);`

Comment: So you're getting an empty response from the API. Everything after that is irrelevant, you need to figure out why that's happening.